# @Override on my own methods?

Tags: android, class, methods, overriding, super

I have a setup similar to what you see below.  I have just noticed that "YourClass" is actually implementing some of my logic from "MyClass."  Ugh.  I tried to throw an @Override above setupViews() in "YourClass" but it won't compile stating, "The method setupViews() of type DataManagerActivity must override a superclass method"

Code changed.  It was an example.  I just typed the wrong thing.  Same question.  How can I keep YourClass that extends MyClass from implementing setupViews() from MyClass?

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setupViews();
        ...

    }

    private void setupViews() {

        ....

    }
}



public class YourClass extends MyClass {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setupViews();
        ...

    }

    private void setupViews() {

        ....

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use 
`this.setupViews();`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  No matter where I tried to put @Override it told me I had to override a superclass method.  I could not get "YourClass" to stop implementing "MyClass" setupViews().  This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

`@Override` instructs the compiler to fail unless the method underneath it overrides a method in the superclass (the one you `extend` from) or one of the `interface`s it implements.

Edit: sorry I may have misinterpreted what you meant. The reason why you can't override `setupViews()` is that it's `private` in `MyClass` so that you *cannot* access or override it from any subclasses.

If that's what you want, then you want your method to be `protected` - as in, accesible and overrideable in subclasses of the class it's defined in, but not accessible from outside.

Edit 2': so bottom line:

If you want `setupViews()` to be overridable in subclasses (such as `YourClass`), make it `protected`. Otherwise, make it `private`.

Comment: That too, but the error that he mentioned was in fact with overriding the `private setupViews()` :)

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Trouble is it's "private" in both.  But there's if (true) { Toast.maketoast } logic in MyClass that is getting displayed in MyClass and YourClass.  Neither the logic nor the tasty toast exist in YourClass.  /me = confused.

Comment: I don't care if it's overrideable, but I definitely don't want it implementing it's stuff in my subclasses :)

Comment: @Dan protected methods can also be accessed by the classes in the same package.